# Escaping a single quote when using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, oracle, spring, escaping, jdbctemplate

We're using [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) to modify our underlying Oracle database. We're doing this by way of the [`update(String sql)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String%29) method.

The code looks somehow like the following:

```
String name = "My name's yellow";
String sql = "update FIELD set NAME = '" + name "' where ID = 10
jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
```

This causes the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The problem is the unescaped `'` in the `name` variable.

What's the most convenient and **correct** way to escape this character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). That way you nominate a placeholder and the JDBC driver will perform this correctly by sending the database the statement, plus the parameters as arguments.

```
    String updateStatement =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
    "where COF_NAME = ?";

    PreparedStatement updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
    updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
    updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
```

The question marks in the above represent the placeholders.

Because these values get passed as parameters, you don't have problems with quoting, and it protects you against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) too.

Comment: I could use JdbcTemplate's [`update(String sql, Object[] args)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29) method which does that automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Try for name :

```
if ( name.contains("'") ){
    name.replaceAll("'", "''");
}
```

Comment: This is an optional solution that is working but not the best solution. Best way is to parameterize the SQL statement to handle all cases as written on other answers.