# Insert the Apostrophe using jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using spring boot jdbctemplate to insert the records in the database. However I found using jdbctemplate.update(query) , where query is the string for inserting the records in the database.

I would like to insert the Apostrophe and special characters in the table columns but I get BadSqlGrammarException.

For example my query gets formed like this 
VALUES(  'abc's example ')

I saw [Escaping a single quote when using JdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956451/escaping-a-single-quote-when-using-jdbctemplate) , Where in comments it is written that using jdbctemplate.update(query,Object[] args) which creates the PreparedStatement , But I have Generic method which calls the jdbctemplate.update() method from every module of the code.

I would like to use this for both insert as well as update operations, as of now I am using jdbctemplate.update(query)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL single quotes are "escaped" by doubling them:

```
VALUES( 'abc''s example ')
```

But it would be **much** better to use a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: What about other character sets ? Do they get handled automatically

Comment: @Chetan: which "other" characters? The single quote is the only one needing escaping in a character constant (in a standard compliant DBMS)

Comment: I mean other special characters

Comment: @Chetan: which "other" special characters?

Comment: All other characters like * , ASCII , + , - , .!@#$%^&*(()

Comment: @Chetan Again: The single quote is the only one needing escaping in a character constant (in a standard compliant DBMS)

Comment: Thanks , I would like to try this solution